# CyberSource SOAP Toolkit Missing?

Tags: soap

I have an install of Magento 1.8.1.0 and for some reason under Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods I'm not seeing "CyberSource (SOAP Toolkit)" as an option.  Authorize.Net is there along with PayPal and others, but not CyberSource.  It's the first time I'm working with CyberSource.

Compilation is disabled:

php -f shell/compiler.php -- state

Compiler Status:          Disabled

Compilation State:        Not Compiled

Collected Files Count:    0

Compiled Scopes Count:    0

> PHP SOAP is installed and available. php -i | grep configure shows:
>
> --enable-soap
>
> --with-openssl
>
> --with-libxml-dir

I've seen other screenshots of the Payment Methods screen showing the CyberSource entry, but not on mine.  Is there something else I have to install?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is install the extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cybersource-extension.html

Yes it hasn't been updated in two years but it's it.  Now the CyberSource (SOAP API) payment method is appearing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not seeing CyberSource (SOAP Toolkit) in your installation is because it is not a native module from Magento. You'll need to contact [CyberSource](http://www.cybersource.com/support/) for support.

EDIT: Not a native module in Magento CE and Enterprise, but integrated in Magento Go. For CE and Enterprise, 3rd party extensions are available, some free, some paid.

Comment: Convert this answer into comment.

Comment: I would comment if I could but I couldn't. My intention was to explain why the author couldn't see CyberSource, which hopefully gives him some idea on his issue and leads him to a solution.

Comment: I contacted CyberSource support and as far as they're concerned Magento is a 3rd party product.  The instructed me in the obvious -- how to enter the keys into Magento -- but only if the option is there under Payment Methods to begin with.  So, no help.  Is CyberSource available in a later version of Magento perhaps and not 1.8.1.0?  I grep'd the Magento source for cybersource and didn't find anything relevant.  Going to download 1.9x now and see.  Down the rabbit hole...

Comment: Wait...it's available in Magento Go: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/payment-methods-cybersource

Comment: Yeah saw it for Magento Go, not for Magento.  Found the answer though. Will post it as such in a moment.